# Bootstrap with KnockOut ? Is it possible in my case

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I designed my view screen with BOOTSTRAP controls and now !

Can i use Data-Bind which we used for binding data while dealing with knockout controls **inside of BOOTSTRAP controls creation .**

Am i am asking this because i have to USE 
KNOCKOUT(**due to its responsiveness i.e sync b/w VM and M**) + 
BOOTSTRAP(**VIEW which can be flexible over multiple devices**) + WEBAPI in my application .

Any suggestions welcome .

Regards

Comment: yes i have used bootstrap and knockout js together in a similar case like yours

Comment: I think you can use them together. There are a lot SPA done with both technologies

Comment: Thank you gentleman for replying . I been confused i.e knockout have controls & bootstrap too having controls . If i use bootstrap controls how can we used Knockout ? any articles explaining this or sample example does it which relates bootstrap & knockout.

Comment: bto.rtz .. seriously i am hoping it would work and i just created a view with say 3 textboxes and 1 dropdown and button which need to post data back . I don't know how to start using knockout in bootstrap any sample work is appreciated .

Comment: Have you tried doing a search on your favorite search engine for `knockout bootstrap`? You'll probably solve your question by yourself if you do so.